# How to define combinations in typescript? Solution: discriminated-union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, discriminated-union, use-reducer

I am using Typescript, I am wondering if it is possible to define what combination can be put into the function. I have following code (very simplified):

```js
interface actionType {
    type: string,
    payload: {
        count?: number,
        first?: number,
        second?: number,
        name?: string,
        message?: string
    }
}

const ADD_ONE = 'addOne'
const MULTIPLY = 'multiply'
const ADD_TOGETHER = 'addTogether',

const theFuntion = (action: actionType) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AddOne": {
      const { count } = action.payload
      const result: number = count + 1
      return result;
    };
    case "Multiply": {
      const { first, second } = action.payload
      const result: number = first * second
      return result;
    };
    case "AddTogether": {
      const { name, message } = action.payload
      const result: string = name + message
      return result;
    };
  }
}
```

Following works:

```
theFuntion({ type: ADD_ONE, payload: { count: 9 } }) // works
theFuntion({ type: MULTIPLY, payload: { first: 3, second: 5 } }) // works
theFuntion({ type: ADD_TOGETHER, payload: { name: 'Peter', message: 'Hello Wolrd!' } }) // works
```

These will and should not work, but does not show type error's:

```
theFuntion({ type: MULTIPLY, payload: { count: 9 } })
theFuntion({ type: ADD_TOGETHER, payload: { first: 3, second: 5 } })
theFuntion({ type: ADD_ONE, payload: { name: 'Peter', message: 'Hello Wolrd!' } })
```

So my question is if there is a way to define an interface or something else to show me if I make a combination error when coding.

SOLUTION:

(Credits: [@matthieu-riegler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884123/matthieu-riegler))

```
type ActionType = 'AddOne' | 'Multiply' | 'AddTogether'

type AddOne = { type: 'AddOne', payload: { count: number } }
type Multiply = { type: 'Multiply', payload: { first: number, second: number } }
type AddTogether = { type: 'AddTogether', payload: { name: string, message: string } }

type Action = AddOne | Multiply | AddTogether;

const theFuntion = (action: Action) => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a discriminated union for that !

```
type ActionType = 'AddOne' | 'Multiply' | 'AddTogether'

type AddOne = { type: 'AddOne', payload: { count: number } }
type Multiply = { type: 'Multiply', payload: { first: number, second: number } }
type AddTogether = { type: 'AddTogether', payload: { nameOfPerson: string, message: string } }

type Action = AddOne | Multiply | AddTogether;

const theFuntion = (action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AddOne": {
      const result: number = action.payload.count + 1
      return result;
    };
    case "Multiply": {
      const result: number = action.payload.first * action.payload.second
      return result;
    };
    case "AddTogether": {
      const result: string = action.payload.nameOfPerson + action.payload.message
      return result;
    };
  }
}

theFuntion({ type: "AddOne", payload: { count: 9 } }) // works

theFuntion({ type: "Multiply", payload: { first: 3, second: 5 } }) // works

theFuntion({ type: "AddTogether", payload: { nameOfPerson: 'Peter', message: 'Hello Wolrd!' } }) // works


// These show an error 

theFuntion({ type: "Multiply", payload: { count: 9 } })

theFuntion({ type: "AddTogether", payload: { first: 3, second: 5 } })

theFuntion({ type: "AddOne", payload: { nameOfPerson: 'Peter', message: 'Hello Wolrd!' } })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYBVzQLxQOQwAmhA8qhHlAD74CyArgDZJiMiU0HHrIDmEwABYQATngCwAKCmhIsYmRxQA3lFkQAXPiKlyeADRQwAQxCNkxwltVxk9VMC2p6AWwBGoqAF9vMrFAZmRFYQKFxVdS08QJY2AyNTc0trKAAzRBEAZ0coZ3dRQ0yIW1QrXNcPEW9fSXV5Qh5%20IU9wtSwonUaBYTFDEzMLMtVUYxcIElSABVFMtC1skURUXkMxzMzjfnngReXqryk-OXgkNDD6xWoApljQmk6%20btEAbkPJEuy1YQAxe1PUc4ACmMCBQqC0JzBAEowgA%20FRSKBQTIAd0QwDggigwNBaAAdOoYcpEUioHBjEUoAAiHSKKnWEmksloT4iCCZG5OCotKAg-54-pJQh42x-KAAaigAEZGaS2cB6CIAWyOcxXpImV51UzyZSqTFgmx6QiNUzmahWezOeV8lVcHywQLEoM8ekssAoAAqXm41BOgaWPFFEqEWVI%20WK5VWtWyrWy3XQGncR7NETG4mmnUsj0q60LJa8c4O-GCl0jMYTaZZM6S4t%200uBtYbfhhqARpVt6PAbWkuOmg6SAcyH5-MGAiLtam08hUvrO5IqZl-LQATn2MIA9BuoCjkCIANaZN7NX4OMcTyBafU3Q0gWcJANDNIZbJaADMhWKaDKAFZ11Atx3PdD2PEczzQcc2kvKdkyaHp7wbJ9y3GKYZjmfBpmAUR4ibTZNHwAAJCBGHMKAAHVkEYERCAAQkoHwvE3bddwPI9pHYwD0GESk0RI3lSmRQQ7EYQhcmQD0WP3Qw3HoD1CGQdkxI9TIhJRKDoFEEQ9zwTINFAiBT3%20SDImpA0QgQ%20cn1FBxV3XfTDPPdSrweODRAsx8UjdV8oA-ZEv1KLQ-wYqF7NHCCL3wpNdAgdyhRSZDKzQ8EMIEbDVnZZt8LwIiSOQcjKOoui7MkIA)

Comment: That is what I was searching for! Thanks!